# Acer Laptop touchpad disable right-click on touchpad (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, touchpad, acer-aspire

The Acer aspire laptop has the ridiculous idea that the right half of the touchpad should be a right-click when two fingers does the same thing.  Really, UI developers?  At least give me a clear way to remove this <strikethrough>"c**p"</strikethrough> "feature" - which I cannot find.

Is there anyway to do this?

- uninstalled Synaptics driver, that only killed the touchpad
- re-installed driver hoping for latest, from the Acer support site - but that just put me back to square one.

How can I do this?  Madness!  Please help :)

Comment: Rather than blowing away the entire Synaptics driver, did you go into the control panel, then the mouse settings to see if there is an option to disable the feature you're talking about?

Comment: No, there is no option available.